# Qmake not installed?

Tags: linux, qt

I'm trying to build a Qt application on RHEL6. It requires Qt 4.8, RHEL only has 4.7. So I've downloaded Qt 4.8 as sources (`qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.6`) and built:

```
./configure
gmake
sudo gmake install
```

No errors, Qt installed in /usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.6/. But I can't find qmake there. There's qmake in the build folder (under bin), but how come it's not installed with the rest of Qt?

Can I feed the new Qt to the qmake from the distro?

EDIT: rebuilt Qt, no errors, still no qmake.

Comment: Are you sure there were no errors/warnings?

Comment: Lots of output there; maybe there was something in the middle. Hard to tell.

Comment: Can you reproduce it with a clean build?

Comment: I can run another Qt build, but it will take hours.

Comment: Do you mean `qmake` instead of `gmake` in listing?

Comment: For building Qt itself, I'm pretty sure gmake is the tool.

Comment: if qmake binary is on your "usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.6/bin" folder, you need to add this directory to the PATH environment variable (export PATH=usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.6/bin:$PATH)

Comment: If you simply run `gmake && sudo gmake install && echo "yay"` in your *existing* build directory, you'll either see "yay" at the end and then you're sure it succeeded, or you'll see the error. There's no reason at all to rebuild. Just retry. If it succeeds, the binary tools should be installed in `/usr/local/*/Qt-4.8.6/bin`.

Comment: Too late, a rebuild is in in progress.